# Change memlock limit in a Docker container; is it possible?

Tags: docker, containers, ubuntu, ssh

I'm running a container from vast.ai, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I'd like to change memlock limit in the Docker container. Is it possible?

What I've already tried:

- Changing the memlock limits in `/etc/security/limits.conf`; tried:

  - `* - memlock -1`
  - `* - memlock unlimited`
  - `root - memlock unlimited`
- Adding `DefaultLimitMEMLOCK=infinity` to `/etc/systemd/system.conf`;
- Adding `UseLogin yes` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`;
- Using `ulimit -l unlimited`, "operation not permitted".

Comment: Hi, how did you manage to solve this on vast.ai?